# How to use array value in where clause in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array `$rest_id` which have 3 ids, but when i do foreach and put this in my sql query there only 1 value appears when i debug it. Here is the code.

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($rest_id as $value) {
    $ids[] = $value->id;
    $nearest_rest = DB::select("SELECT *, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( 28.5812674 - lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( 28.5812674 * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( 77.3181059 - lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance from restaurant_details where id In ('" . implode("','",$ids) . "') having distance order by distance asc limit 1"); 

     dd($nearest_rest);
}
```

Comment: watch `limit 1` at the end!

Comment: your query is inside your foreach()

Comment: should i do my query out of foreach ..

Comment: Thanks @nogad it's working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this, if you want to get the nearest restaurant out of 3 ids:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($rest_id as $value) {
    $ids[] = $value->id;
}

$nearest_rest = DB::select("SELECT *, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( 28.5812674 - lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( 28.5812674 * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( 77.3181059 - lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance from restaurant_details where id In ('" . implode("','",$ids) . "') having distance order by distance asc limit 1"); 

dd($nearest_rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$ids = implode(',',$ID)` function to convert array into string.

Then you can use `where id in ($ids)` in your query